# Read from next spreadsheet in python

Tags: python, csv

I am reading csv files in python and my first worksheet has filled the 1048576 row limit and I would like to continue reading from the second worksheet from my for loop. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using?
Also, you may want to take a look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) if you're not using it already

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading a csv file or a xls file? Can a csv file even have separate worksheets?

Overall i would recommend to use openpyxl which is a great library for reading xls files and their worksheets.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

Would enable to list all available worksheets

```
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('worksheet123')
```

allows to load the desired worksheet for further processing